# Getting Files to show up on new submitted Module page

Tags: 7, version-control

I have a module that is ready for public use, and I have created a Drupal Account and created a development sandbox, and even uploaded the files via git. Now, I am very much a newb regarding git, so perhaps I have done something wrong. I have attached 2 screenshots of my module page screens (public facing page and the edit page).

[image][image]

Now I am pretty sure that the reason I cannot promote to a full project as seen on [this page](https://drupal.org/node/1068952) is because I need to create an issue so that the Drupal team can review the module. [This page](https://drupal.org/node/1011698) says to create an issue with specific details included. However, for Component, I am supposed to select either 'Module', 'Theme', or 'Feature'. I would like to select Module, but the only options that are provided at this time are 'Code', 'Documentation', 'Miscellaneous', and 'User Interface'. What am I missing? What additional steps do I need to follow to get this module publicly published?

Answer (score 0):

Found answer. Apparently I missed the part where sandboxes do not have download buttons on the project pages. And I was trying to add an issue for MY project, rather than submit an issue to Drupal.org.